# Artifactory - Unlock Cocoapods, Nuget,

Tags: maven, nuget, cocoapods, open-source, artifactory

I have installed JFrog Artifactory OSS on my server to store all librairies which I have written.

I can create Maven repository but when I want to create a Cocoapods, a Nuget or a PHP Composer repository I can't do it (I can't select them on the list of repository type choice).

Do you know if it's a bug or if I need to upgrade to the Pro version ?

Sincerely,
KevSib

Comment: What happens when you try? Any errors? Post your commands / attempts and the error messages or stack traces. Anything in some log files?

Comment: You should *accept* (tick the green sign) the answer below, it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NuGet and PHP repository support requires the [Pro](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/versions/#pro) version of Artifactory.
For more a comparison between the OSS/Pro/Enterprise version please take a look at the [Artifactory feature matrix](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/).